# Can anyone clear up some concerns about replication differences between Oracle and MS SQL Server?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

The following shows the replication capabilities as described for ms sql server on oracle
website.

"the text inside the " " are my questions/confusion AGAINST what oracle website says"

Please clear these points, what do you think? Is this article out of date?

> Replication functionality in Microsoft
>   SQL Server or Sybase Adaptive Server
>   has the following characteristics:
>
> - Unidirectional "merge replication supports!!"
> - Table-based, not transaction-based "in transaction replication new
>     changes/transactions are replicated in
>     real time!!!"
> - No automatic conflict resolution (must be manual) "Really? what about
>     merge replication"??
> - Heterogeneous replication through Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)
>
> In addition to the preceding
>   characteristics, Microsoft SQL Server
>   7.0 replication provides heterogeneous replication through ODBC.
>
> Oracle replication has richer
>   replication functionality, which
>   includes the following:
>
> - Bi-directional
> - Any database object can be replicated
> - Automatic resynchronization
> - Automatic conflict resolution
> - Heterogeneous replication provided through gateways

Comment: The text mentions SQL Server 7 which is very old (late 90s).

Comment: Even SQL Server 7 had multi master replication and IIRC automatic conflict resolution.

Comment: wow, this was a fast edit and very very fast answers. thanku all. reallt really sorry for such a question i gues the part sql server 7 did not ring any bells :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is marketing material about direct competitor accurate, up to date and unbiased? Use your brain, user287745...

SQL Server 7.0 is rather old. Since then 4 (four) more major editions have shipped (2000, 2005, 2008 and R2). If you want to read about SQL Server Replication, you better read on the MSDN site. [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Outdated. Really. or worse, whoever wrote that at oracle... left information out on purpose.